# JNA mapping for uint8_t and int8_t

Tags: java, c, jna

What are the correct JNA mappings of the C types uint8_t and int8_t? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only 8-bit integer data type in Java is `byte`, so you would use that. Unfortunately it is signed, so `uint8_t` values over 127 will be seen as negative when converted into Java `byte`. This is not really a problem because the stored bits are the same.